# Is it acceptable interrogative?

Tags: grammaticality

One friend from Iraq sent me a message on Facebook asking, "what is the form interrogative to the following ? "

The messages are from Sameera and Mr. Abdulla.

I found the answer in their book the ( curriculum ) as  :

Who are the messages from?

I searched thousand books of Google and never found "  Who are the messages ( something) from?"

i.e . I did not find (Who are the **messages** from ?) or any **object** else

Is it grammatically correct?

It seems to me not usual language or bad language!

Answer (score 1):

"Who are the messages from?" is standard English, and has plenty of examples in published books eg [Tailor Made](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Tailor_Made/DRIQEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22Who+are+the+messages+from%22&pg=PT69&printsec=frontcover)

More generally "Who are (the something) from?" is a common construction.  For example "Who are the flowers from?"

The construction goes as follows:

> The flowers are from Sarah.  (SVC sentence with prepositional phrase as complement

> The flowers are from who  (replace "Sarah" with interogative pronoun "who".)

> Who the flowers are from (*Front* the pronoun)

> Who are the flowers from? (invert the subject and verb.

[Dixon](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=wUa0HpVaoIYC&newbks=0&hl=en&source=newbks_fb&redir_esc=y) says: "If the constituent being questioned had a preposition associated with it, then this may either be moved to initial position, before the wh- word, or it can be left in its underlying position in the clause."

That means that for both "From whom are the messages" and "Who are the messages from" are correct forms.

---

Dixon: *A New Approach to English Grammar, on Semantic Principles*

Comment: thank you   I meant by ( something)  putting it between brackets = anything else  messages or any object    Why can't you get language   ?

Comment: 2.  This is not grammar book.  Many writers are not native speakers and make mistakes in grammar. I neve depend on.   If you say the truth, give me an example from books of grammar British or American.

Comment: I challenge you to offer me one example like the mentioned from one grammar book

Comment: @Ahmad Mohammad I, and a good many other people, consider that correct English is defined by what ordinary, and particularly well-educated users of the language say and write, not by what is in grammar books. hen one can find many published uses of a phrase or a construction, particularly in books published by major publishers, that indicates that it is correct English, and there is no need to consult grammar books.

Comment: @ David Siegel   Only grammar books convery the right language 
 I don't agree with you because everyday I find mistakes even in some grammar books and you can find my reviews in Google.  When I am suspected in any phrase or item of grammar I go and search to compare the results until I am sure of the result. The sentence I brought I never heard or read in all of my life ; therefore it became strange to me.  It is perhaps less used by native speakers  ( this form of interrogative )  I also have friends in Espresso online learning English and messaged them and replied to my message . (used)

Comment: I've added the link.  I think you are concerned about the prepostion at the end, so I've cited a grammar book as you asked for to say that this is correct.

Comment: Thank you I read it. This is common in English adjective comes in front and can stand without supporting participle. I wrote some comments in another domain: Sometimes I fear of using language unless I found in trusted books or mentioned by trusted authors.

Since the internet is full of grammar mistakes and anyone can write in the internet.

Nodays, most people who are writing in the internet are not native and hardly themselves understand the language.

I hid my IP address because Google sometimes forbid us or hide the results to be seen, however, no result I found.